# What is the equivalent of ALAssetsGroupPropertyURL for iOS 4.0

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary, assetslibrary

Since ALAssetsGroup or not valid after the life of ALAssetsLibrary
I'm saving ALAssetsGroupPropertyURL from valueForProperty
but this property is only available from iOS 5.0
How does one can get a hold of it in iOS 4.0+ ?

Comment: what do you want to save or persist?

Comment: i wanted to pass the url to be called with groupForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock: in another controller

Answer (score 1):

I went the ALAssetsGroupPropertyPersistentID way ...
since groupForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock: is for iOS 5.0+ anyways